# How to pass php array to bash script

Tags: php, bash

My bash script call a php file

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(./getconfig.php)
```

The file getconfig.php is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$array = array();
...
```

How can I return the `$array` from the php file in order to manipulate this array in the bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), an array is initialized with the following syntax:

```
farm_hosts=(web03 web04 web05 web06 web07)
```

So all you need to do is implode your `$array`:

```
echo implode(' ', $array);
```

Comment: Amazing, I can't believe it's so simple. I also want to add that for some reason, bash reads the PHP array backwards (last item in PHP is first item in bash).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `=()` format to read lines into an array like this

```
data = (`./getconfig.php`)
```

You would just need to make sure your PHP script output one line for each item in the array or there is a space between each item.

The key here is using backticks to get the replacement value from PHP script output.

Comment: Thank you! It was necessary too!